# How to implement observation if we already used intheritance?

Tags: php, observer-pattern

There is a `ForumThread` class:

```
class ForumThread extends DbTable
{
    public function insert ($threadId, $comment)
    {
        SQL INSERT INTO parent::tablename VALUES $threadId, $comment
        // email sending how?
        // putting this on a "notice-wall", how?
    }
}
```

some other functions should be done here, e.g. email sending. I cant put it here otherwise I violate the SRP. I cant put it neither to `controller`, as I want to insert post elsewhere too. Im planning to implement the Observed pattern, but I cant extend from two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the observer pattern you would have to dispatch a notification from 
this method in order to execute the relevant observers code.

You would execute something like this from within the insert method:

```
$this->notify('table_insertion', $data);
```

Then somewhere else before the notify line is executed, the event must be registered like so:

```
static::$observers['table_insertion'][] = array('class_to_call' => 'method_in_class_to_call');
```

The notify method would be something like:

```
public function notify($event, $data) {
  foreach(static::$observer[$event] as $class => $method) {
    new $class->$method($data);
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.